# Writing a class for JSON data with multiple possible types for a field

Tags: c#, json, json.net, discriminated-union

Stepping out of the Python world and into C#, I'm having a bit of trouble defining a class which can be used for decoding my JSON payload.

In Python I usually use Pydantic for this type of problem, so I will illustrate with that:

```py
from typing import Literal, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Foo(BaseModel):
    kind: Literal["foo"]
    fizz: int

class Bar(BaseModel):
    kind: Literal["bar"]
    buzz: str

Payload = Union[Foo, Bar]

class Message(BaseModel):
    payload: Payload
```

The class message adheres to the following JSON schema:

```yaml
type: object
required: [payload]
properties:
  payload:
    anyOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/Foo'
    - $ref: '#/definitions/Bar'
definitions:
  Foo:
    type: object
    required: [kind, fizz]
    properties:
      kind: {enum: [foo], type: string}
      fizz: {type: integer}
  Bar:
    type: object
    required: [kind, buzz]
    properties:
      kind: {enum: [bar], type: string}
      buzz: {type: string}
```

After researching I can't figure out the best way to map these concepts to C#. From what I understand, C# does not have a literal string types, so I can't use those. I'm also unsure of the correct way to define the `Union` type.

What would be the most pragmatic way to model a Class for this payload in C# such that I can decode and encode this data as JSON? So far I have been using `Newtonsoft.Json` but I am open to other tooling if that makes this easier.

I'm imagining in the C# version I would have something like this:

```
interface Payload
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
}

class Foo : Payload
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public int fizz { get; set; }
}
class Buzz : Payload
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public string buzz { get; set; }
}

class Message
{
    public Payload Payload { get; set; }
}
```

(but I'm unsure of what the magic Newtonsoft code would look like to tie it all together)

Comment: One question, did you try to paste your JSON into one of the JSON to C# Class websites? eg https://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @JeremyThompson I don't think that tool would work here. It seems to merge `fizz` and `buzz` into the same object.

Comment: I would use JObject to parse and create such json. In just a few lines of code, I stuffed the data to/from the necessary classes and properties. It's pragmatic.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Anything you would change about the answer I posted? When all is said and done there will probably be about 30-40 different Payload types.

Comment: `ReadJson` method in your `PayloadConverter` do the stuff. `JObject.Load` + `switch` is what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this I what I ended up with, but it feels super awkward...

Maybe someone can suggest improvements:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
...

public interface Payload { }

public class Foo : Payload
{
    [JsonProperty("kind")]
    public string Kind { get; set; } = "foo";

    [JsonProperty("fizz")]
    public int Fizz { get; set; };
}

public class Bar : Payload
{
    [JsonProperty("kind")]
    public string Kind { get; set; } = "bar";

    [JsonProperty("buzz")]
    public string Buzz { get; set; };
}

public class Message
{
    [JsonProperty("payload")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PayloadConverter))]
    public Payload Payload { get; set; }
}
```

And then defining a custom JsonConverter for message:

```
public class PayloadConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) =>
        typeof(Payload).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, 
        Type objectType,
        object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);

        Payload item = obj["kind"].ToString() switch
        {
            "foo" => new Foo(),
            "bar" => new Bar(),
            _ => null
        };
        if (item == null) return null;
        serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), item);
        return item;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer, 
        object value, 
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```